# Tinymce editor change border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-6

How to change the color of the tinymce editor outer border by pressing a button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your Tinymce editor is added to your page, if like [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/?/?utm_source=google_ads&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_campaign=sitelink&utm_term=tinymce%20editor&utm_content=docs&gclid=CjwKCAjwzuqgBhAcEiwAdj5dRkCOLlhWwBj4bGJ5D37shID8vbjhjdoU0Qa_ST2-5bzFnA5Hy5EWihoC7cYQAvD_BwE) then you can simply:

```
<button id="change">Change</button>

document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function() {
   tinymce.get('tinymce_textarea')['editorContainer'].style.borderColor = 'red';
});
```

Where `tinymce_textarea` is id of your `textarea`

Comment: I tried your answer, But it didn't work. Please check this fiddle. 
https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Q2iaab/1

Comment: @udi You are right, replace getBody() with ['editorContainer'] and that will do the job. Updated the answer.